# One-more co-CDH assumption in pairing group

Tags: pairings, random-oracle-model, co-cdh

I am asking it again because no one answered my previous question with more clarity. I have deleted that question

One more co-CDH in Type three pairing groups $G_1 \times G_2 \to G_T$: means given a generator $g_2$ in $G_2$, $A = g_2^a$ with random $a$ and an oracle $\mathcal{O}$ which which accepts query $Q \in G_1$ and outputs $( Q^a)$ no one should be able to produce a set $ S = \{(q_1, H((q_1))^a),(q_2, H((q_2))^a)..(q_{n+1}, H((q_{n+1}))^a) \}$  with $H:\{0,1\}^* \to G_1$ being a random oracle with $|S| > n$ with $n$ being the number of queries made to $\mathcal{O}$ except with negligible probability.

Has this problem been defined? Or should I introduce it as new assumption? I have tried searching google scholar but cannot find anything that has this name.

EDIT: Sorry I made error in placing parentheses. I have fixed it

EDIT: I am trying to use adapted form of OPAQUE (with pairing fiendly curves for verification) in my own research. Can someone help?

Comment: Does $q_1$ refer to $Q \in G_1$? Your definition of the assumption remains unclear as there are some undeclared variables, for example, $a, q_i$.

Comment: @mingalex I had made mistakes in placing parenthesis. I have since fixed. $a$ is a random number in $F_q$ $q$ being the order of all of the groups chosen by the challenger. $H$ is a random oracle which outputs a point in $G_1$. $q_i$ is any bit string of arbitrary size (polynomially bounded), chosen by the adversary.

Comment: I think you should add a restricted condition, that is $\{H(q_i)\}_{i \in [n+1]} \cap \{Q\} = \emptyset$. If so, I guess your one more coCDH assumption can be reduced to both DL assumption and coCDH assumption.

Comment: @mingalex Did you mean if I prevent the adversary from querying $H(q_i)$ directly to the oracle, we can reduce it to coCDH and DL assumption? Can you show me how? Or did you misunderstand $Q$ as some given value? It is just a variable to refer to any query that the oracle accepts.   Generally in my use case they are supposed to send blinded queries $H(q_i)^{r_i}$ with random $r_i$ but I cannot restrict malicious agent from sending unblinded queries or queries in combination.

Comment: Without the restricted condition I mentioned, the adversary could adaptively query the oracle at any time, then it would trivially obtain the set $S$ you defined by submitting a set $\{ H(q_i)\}_{i \in [n+1]}$ to the oracle. I suggest you refer to the EUF-CMA or IND-CPA attack models to prove your assumption.

Comment: @mingalex The adversary only makes $n$ queries by definition. An honest guy makes blinded queries $H(q_i)^{r_i}$ with random $r_i$. But an adversary may query it any way it likes like unblinded queries or combined queries like $GH(q_1)^{r_1}H(q_2)^{r_2}$. Requirement is that the adversary should not be able to produce more such pairs than queries to the oracle except with negligible probability.

Comment: No one to answer yet. Basically, I am trying to adapt OPAQUE but with pairing friendly curves so that the server's response is publicly verifiable. It is done on a blockchain .....